# How do I ensure regex URL matching does not match an email?

Tags: regex, url

I have a regex that I wrote for matching URLs:

```
(?:\w+:\/{2})?(?:\w+:\w+@)?(?:\w+(?:\.|-\w+)*\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}(?::\d+)?(?:\/[^\s]*)?(?:\?\S*)?
```

Here's the breakdown:

```
(?:\w+:\/{2})?          http://
(?:\w+:\w+@)?       username:password@
(?:\w+(?:\.|-\w+)*\.)+    google.us.
[a-zA-Z]{2,}            .com, .org. co, io
(?::\d+)?                   :8080
(?:\/[^\s]*)?             /about/us
(?:\?\S*)?                 Query parmas ?utm_param=Facebook
```

However, this regex is matching 'david@google.com'. How can I make sure that any urls in emails are not included? I have tried adding

```
(?<!@)
```

to the beginning of the regex, but no luck.

Comment: Since your pattern allows for username/password and makes the protocol optional, what you ask is impossible.  `david@google.com` is a valid partial URL, with username "david".

Comment: If you're pulling these from other documents, perhaps you should skip the username/password parts, which are not commonly embedded in documents.

Comment: Yeah, known issue. Match emails, or match and capture URLs.

Answer (score 0):

You would have to define at least some URL chrome -- perhaps the protocol, or a trailing slash after the host -- as mandatory, or disallow HTTP username specification, in order to stop matching email addresses with your pattern.